# How to use flask-oauthlib with flask-login together?

Tags: python, flask, single-sign-on, flask-login, flask-oauthlib

For now, I'm trying to use `flask-oauthlib` with `flask-login` together.

`flask-oauthlib` provides a simple way to use `oauth`, but I want a login manager to automatically redirect all users who are not logged in to `/login`. In `flask-login`, I can use `login_required` to accomplish this. But how could I achieve this by `flask-oauthlib`?

Further, how to manage session when using `flask-oauthlib`? I understand how SSO works, but I'm confusing how could I know if this token is expired or not?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've spent some time thinking about this (as I want to do it for my own website), and I've come up with a theoretical solution.

From what I understand in my implementation of Google's OAuth API, OAuth is about sending the user on a link to the server that hosts the OAuth keys, and then returning back to the sender. So, my idea is that in the login form, you have buttons that act as links to the OAuth client.

I haven't tested this, but since no one else has replied to this I figure this will give you a nice little project to implement yourself and let us know if it works.

Comment: Actually, I have rethought my problem, and finally I realized that there is no need to take care about the token is expired or not. If it is, just re-authenticate it. And OAUTH is just working at the first step——login. After authenticating this user, the management of user's session is handled by third-party application itself. To sum up, OAUTH is just used for authenticating user but not managing session.

Comment: @sraw yes. OAuth has nothing to do with sessions, you could manage it with Flask.